# Insert spaces in particular places on particular lines in .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to write a program that opens a text file and inserts spaces after the *5th, 6th and 7th* word for every line beginning with `C_PIN`.

I feel that I have it almost complete but I've benn getting run-time errors 5 and 438.

Example text being read:

---

> COMP C48 66250110810 cap sc_cap.0603_H9  43.3959 74.3331 1   0
>   C_PROP (PB_FREE,"Y") (VALUE,"10nF") (TOLER,"10%") (PART_NAME,"06035C103K4T2A")
>   C_PIN C48-1 43.3959 75.0951  1  1  0 sp.0603_H9.1 /N$1567
>   C_PIN C48-2 43.3959 73.5711  1  1  0 sp.0603_H9.2 GN

---

An extra space is required after the `1 1 0`

Here's where I think the problem in my code lies:

```
x = " "
Do While Not EOF(infilenum%)
 Line Input #infilenum%, a$
  If Left$(a$, 5) = "C_PIN" Then
   For Each x In InStr
   'If InStr(strText, " ") Then
     w = w + 1
    'w = strText.Split
     For w = 5 To w = 7
      My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText (infilename$)
      strText = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(infilename$).Replace(w, x + w)
      vb.newline
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: please, show complete of your code including loops ending and `end if`...

Comment: Here's a Link to the full code. http://pastebin.com/TrJbaYuz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with an alternative version that uses a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to make a single shot replacement

While it looks a little complicated, the plus - other than a single shot replacement - is that it *only* will alter lines that

- start with `C_PIN`
- have (at least) a further 6 words

This sample take your initial file, and saves a second version with the padded spacing.

*Upated for additional requirement, using two separate regexp replacements*

```
Sub ReDo()
Dim objFso As Object
Dim objFil As Object
Dim objFil2 As Object
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strAll As String

strFil = "c:\temp\REnglish.txt"
strFil2 = "c:\temp\REnglish2.txt"

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "(\nC_PIN\s)((\b[^\s]+\b\s){3})(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b\d\b\s)"
.Global = True
Set objFil = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFil)
strAll = objFil.ReadAll
Set objFil2 = objFso.createtextfile(strFil2)
strAll = .Replace(strAll, "$1$2$3$4 $5 $6 ")
.Pattern = "(\nC_PIN\s)((\b[^\s]+\b\s){3})(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b[^\s]+\b\s)(\b\d{2,}\b\s)"
objFil2.write .Replace(strAll, "$1$2$3$4 $5 $6")
End With
objFil.Close
objFil2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I've just tried implementing this new code and got a run-time error 53. Can you explain that?

Comment: on line:                                                            Set objFil = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFil)

Comment: did you update `StrFil` to match the path of your textfile on your machine (and `StrFil2 for that matter)?

Comment: No not yet. I just ran the code to see if it would work. I was going to use some other code. this would prompt the user to choose a file to open and alos create a file for the output. I already have the first part of that but not the second.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. I've been messing around with this for a few days and it finally works. Here's a link to the full working program: http://pastebin.com/jFDDRtuV

Comment: I'm still finding this hard to understand. Though I've managed to get it to work I'm hoping to alter it slightly so that no space is placed in if the 7th word has a value greater than 9. I've tried using an 'If' statement after this bit of new code but I only get an error becuase I've referenced '$7' outside of 'strAll'. Is there an easy reference for the 7th word or does this require more code?

Comment: Hi Robert - more code to alter the regexp match. I will get to this later today (this is verging on a new question)

Comment: Thanks brettdj. I'm going to keep working on it anyways. Should this be posted as a seperate question?

Comment: `Regex` is difficult to pick up, but invaluable when learnt. With the new adjustment, will the file be a mix of te 7th string being numbers > 9 (ie will the code need to test each match?)

Comment: Yes, the 7th number will be both larger and smaller than 9 on different lines. If the 7th word is greater than 9, no extra space is added to the string. I hadn't predicted this new change. If I had known I would have asked this in the initial question.

Comment: It calls for a line by line approach rather than single shot global replacement. I will work through this to day. Up to you as to whether this is an update, or a new question.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Is there any reason I'm now getting a Run-Time error 5?

Comment: In my own code I've placed in my own file name but here's the line with your file name _Set objFil = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFil)_

Comment: It's not finding your own path and file then Robert - suggest you look again at that part.

Comment: Would it be possible for you (or anyone for that matter) to explain this code? I've been reading through it and can't seem to get my head around anything after the variables are initialised.

Comment: Regexp isn't easy. The best VBA article is [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/A_1336-Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html) by Patrick Matthews. But the reason your code is failing did appear to be the location of your txt file

Comment: I've just opened all of the files I've been tring to convert. There's no text now. Before there was lines upon lines of text, now there's nothing. I've found that the run-time error 5 was only occurring for files I've tried more than once. For files I run on their first time I get a run-time error 438 - "Object does not support this property or method" on this line of code, `objFil2.writestrAll = .Replace(strAll, "$1$2$3$4 $5 $6 ")`. Here's a link to the full code to clear up any questions, http://pastebin.com/xsi6gyZ6

Comment: Rob, I don't get any errors unless the inout file is completely blank (then I get an erro 62 on `strAll = objFil.ReadAll`). This code writes to a new file `c:\temp\REnglish2.txt` - unless you used the sample name for both `objFil1` and `objFil2`? So I don't think the code would have "blanked" out the originals.

Comment: I think I've solved the txt deleting problem. But instead of having a fixed directory in the code I need to just edit the txt file and save the changes to the same file, or at the very least have a prompt for Save As window to pop up.

Comment: Would it be possible to use some sort of Streamwriter? How could that be implemented?

Comment: You can close `objFil1` then directly write over it after the `regexp` replacement (rather than creating a new file)

Answer (score 3):

```
For Each x In InStr
```

isn't valid in any way!!!

You can use Split and Join:

```
If Left(a, 5) = "C_PIN" Then
    va = Split(a, " ")
    va(4) = va(4) & " " 'Add extra space
    va(5) = va(4) & " "
    va(6) = va(4) & " "
    a =  Join(va, " ") 'Join with extra spaces added
End If
```

Now you can write the string.

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried the code. I was given; Run-time error 9 'Subscript out of range'. This obviously has to do with my code not yours.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What was so wrong about my initial code? I had pulled it together from a few different (working) programs. Surely some parts should have worked?

Comment: `For Each` iterates through items in a Collection, but InStr returns an Variant (Long). `My.Computer.FileSystem` is from VB.NET and as far as I know, VBA is not .NET (yet?)

Comment: This solution has low overhead compared to RegEx scripting - it is a huge overhead for such a simple task. I admit, however, that maybe the RegEx.Replace function call may be faster than VBA running my code.

Comment: I've tried both solutions and would use your code if it had open/close fiile operations. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I found this page on the MSDN. It's very helpful in explaining the \b, \d, \s and \n comands. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx